# How do I know the subclass type?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift. I was studying Inheritance. I have a method that takes in Character. Character is a super class here, and Player and Enemy are its subclasses. I would either pass Player or Enemy in the parameter of this method. How do I check which type of Character I am dealing with? Is it a Player or a Enemy?

```
func deadCharacter(character: Character) {}
```

Comment: `if character is Player { }` and `if character is Enemy { }`.  You might want to pick a better name for your base class because `Character` is a basic Swift type.

Answer (score 1):

```
if passedInCharacter.isKindOfClass(Player) {
    //do what you want to do with player
} else if passedInCharacter.isKindOfClass(Enemy) {
    //do what you want to do with enemy
}
```

I also agree with vacawama that you probably have to think of a better name for Character class.